# Unbiased estimate of the semi-partial correlation

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, bias, unbiased-estimator, partial-correlation

- Is the sample semi-partial correlation a biased estimate of the population semi-partial correlation?
- If it is biased, what is an unbiased estimator of the population semi-partial correlation?
- Are there are any references in the statistical literature that discuss this?

Comment: I think it is biased, like any correlation. I'm not sure for the second point, but to hint: knowing that $r_{x(y.z)}=\sqrt{R_{x.yz}^2-r_{xz}^2}$ if you take for those R and r their unbiased (adjusted) versions, won't the result be also unbiased?