# Relative importance (explained variation) of variables in non-linear models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, normalization, ordinal-data, importance

I have two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, which are correlated. I want to know which of those variables explains more variation in $y$.

I know that for linear regression, there are a bunch of options (which are discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79399/calculate-variance-explained-by-each-predictor-in-multiple-regression-using-r), in addition you can find the paper for a recommended package here: [Grömping, 2006](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v017i01/v17i01.pdf)).

Regrettably, my regression is pretty poorly explained by OLS*. Instead, I am using a quasibinomial distribution (In `R` this corresponds to `glm` with family `quasibinomial`. In Stata this corresponds to `fracreg logit`). **(If any of these solutions DO work for my type of model, please let me know)** Nevertheless, I still want to test for relative importance, in the best way I can (in either R or Stata).

I thought the best way to test this, would to be to just normalise both variables.

1. However, now the first question arises. If I want to test which variable explains more variation in a generalized linear model,

A) do I test:

$$y = B_0 + B_1x_1 + B_2x_2 + u$$

B) Or do I test:

$$y = B_0 + B_1x_1 + u - versus - y = B_0 + B_2x_2 + u$$

Now, to make the example slightly more complicated, let's assume that $x_1$ is an ordinal variable. Now I know already that normalising ordinal data is at a minimum frowned upon (See for example [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113554/can-i-normalize-ordinal-data), [link](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-normalise-ordinal-data), [link](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/92077-any-way-to-standardize-ordinal-categorical-variables)). Here I note that I am not looking for the perfect solution. Instead, I am looking for the best I can do. So the next question:

2. What are my options if $x_1$ is an ordinal variable?

If I could make it even slightly more complicated,

3. What if $x_2$ (NOT $x_1$) was a dummy variable (at this point we are comparing an ordinal variable to a dummy variable, which are correlated)?

Once again, I am not looking for perfect solutions. I am looking for the best I can do. References and package recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

*My first idea was to simply use a linear model to compare these variables. But the model was so poorly explained by OLS that I refrained.

## EDIT:

The `domin` ([Stata-package](https://github.com/jluchman/domin.)) / `domir` ([R-package](https://github.com/jluchman/domir)) packages allow checking for relative importance in non-linear models. I could however not find any literature on the application in relation to non-linear models).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tom noted a model like `glm(family=quasibinomial())` is possible using `domir::domin` in R or `domin` from SSC in Stata (see answer on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1607459-is-there-any-way-in-stata-to-determine-relative-importance-explained-variation-of-variables-in-nonlinear-models)).

As applied in R, consider this model:

```
> mtcars2 <- cbind(mtcars, carb2 = mtcars$carb/8)
> qbn_mod <- glm(carb2 ~ vs + am + disp, family=quasibinomial(), data=mtcars2)
> qbn_mod

Call:  glm(formula = carb2 ~ vs + am + disp, family = quasibinomial(), 
    data = mtcars2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           vs           am         disp  
  -0.924444    -0.835746     0.528684     0.001797  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  28 Residual
Null Deviance:      6.02 
Residual Deviance: 3.932    AIC: NA
```

Have to do a workaround for a fit metric.  In this case, just the squared correlation between the observed and predicted values.

```
> predict(qbn_mod, type="response") |> (\(x) cor(x, mtcars2$carb2)^2)()
[1] 0.3945242
```

With a fit metric, now can complete the `domin` call.

```
> domir::domin(carb2 ~ vs + am + disp, glm, list(\(x) list("R2" = cor(predict(x, type="response"), mtcars2$carb2)^2), "R2"), family=quasibinomial(), data=mtcars2)
Overall Fit Statistic:      0.3945242 

General Dominance Statistics:
     General_Dominance Standardized Ranks
vs          0.22780384    0.5774141     1
am          0.05728333    0.1451960     3
disp        0.10943706    0.2773900     2

Conditional Dominance Statistics:
          IVs: 1     IVs: 2     IVs: 3
vs   0.324452295 0.26944926 0.08950998
am   0.003310202 0.09892875 0.06961106
disp 0.150051448 0.15108247 0.02717726

Complete Dominance Statistics:
           Dmned?vs Dmned?am Dmned?disp
Dmate?vs          0        0          1
Dmate?am          0        0          0
Dmate?disp       -1        0          0
```

There's a couple of papers on `glm`s ([Azen & Tranel, 2009](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/1076998609332754)), as well as `MASS::polr` and `nnet::multnom` ([Luchman, 2014](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428114544509)) and `pscl::zeroinfl` ([Luchman, Lei, & Kaplan, 2020](https://jasemjournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Luchman-et-al-2020-Vol4Issue2.pdf)) that examine nonlinear models' importance.